Deleted question?
There was an interesting question about a person sporadically losing her ability to see or walk. It was, I believe, flagged for being a self-help question. I would like to edit the question and answer it, but cannot find it anymore. If it has been deleted by a moderator, could you please undelete it to make it accessible to me?

Could you give some words that you remember being in the title, or other phrases I could use to try and fish it out to see?

The person asking the question mentioned not being able to see ("see", "blind", "blindness") and being unable to move or walk ("unable", "inability", "walk", "move"). Unfortunately I don't remember any more, and I don't know if those words were actually part of the question.

Not having any luck going by those terms - I think Steven's recommendation below is probably your best bet.

I couldn't find the question immediately, but perhaps you could simply write up a new question yourself and answer it in one go as well? This is something which is allowed on Stack Exchange. 
The question probably was deleted for a good reason in the first place and you would have to rephrase it thoroughly either way.

I'm not able to fish it out either, shame though because I'm now rather intrigued as to what was in it. Good advice - it's probably better at this point for what to share his knowledge, Q&A style.

I'll do that, then, I'm just unhappy that I could not provide an answer to the person who was asking it. I know that self-help questions are not allowed here, but I do like to provide information that will help them find help after they left here.

Okay, I wrote the question and provided an answer. If you feel this is not sufficient, let me know. Thank you all for your help!
